# Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Tags: python, json

I have scraped some html and want to create a json doc. Here is the code I currently have:

```
with open(path.join(path.abspath(path.curdir),'Results\\html.txt'), 'r') as file:

    for line in file.readlines():
        if not line.strip():
            continue

        if re.findall(r'\"aggregateRating.*\"telephone\"',line):
            reviews = re.findall(r'\[.*\]', line)

            json_data = json.loads(str(reviews))
```

The error I get is: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

Any help is appreciate. I have been stuck on this for awhile..

Comment: Are we supposed to guess at what the data looks like?

Comment: `print` is a powerful tool. `print` out `reviews` and see if that is something sensible you can even feed `json.loads` with.

Comment: Your code is trying to load the string representation of a list as a valid json string.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to load the string representation of a list as a valid json string; which of course will not work.

It is the same as trying to do this:

```
>>> json.loads(str(['hello world']))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

If you are trying to write the result as json; you need to do the opposite of `loads`, which is `dumps`:

```
>>> json.dumps(str(['hello world']))
'"[\'hello world\']"'
```